# How to implement BottomSheet in Android API 25

Tags: android

Im using Android API 25, everything fine with configure following as:

**(UPDATED TO V25.0.1)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
 ... 
}

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
 }
```

But I when I add more library (BottomSheet):

```
//Design support Library
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Compiler will display an alert: error message, and can not implements.
And then, If I continue to update to latest version:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Everything will fine, but BottomSheet in my code will not active(can not scroll up). It seem can not integrate BottomSheet in Version 25

I don't know why, How to fix this problem ?

Comment: First, synchronize your support library versions. Ignoring `com.android.support:design`, you are using `24.2.0`, `25.0.0`, and `25.0.1`. Pick **one** of those and use if for **all** the `com.android.support` dependencies. I recommend `25.0.1`, since it is the latest and may have relevant bug fixes. Then, if you still are having your problem, please explain what "will not active" means and show the relevant code.

Comment: yes, 'will not active': my meaning is when I click a button, there is a dialog in  bottom will scroll up and appear. (BottomSheet)

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have updated almost to version 25.0.1 API, but it still happened exception, I can not use ButtomSheet in version 25, If back Version 23 to use ButtomSheet, it's very inconvenience

Comment: Same issue here, have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Alex: You can use BottomSheet for v.24, example: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1' (rememberd: update all lib to 24) Bottomsheet will fine

Comment: Just find a solution. I juste have to define a peek height

Comment: Hi @Alex: can you create new topic ? I want to know your matter